# Adding two numbers using Client Server Multi threading programming in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, sockets

The below client server program is not giving me any out put. I want to add two numbers. I am new Java programming. After entering second number , there is blank space below. What's wrong am doing below. Please help me solve this issue. Thanks.

Client.Java

```
        package Client.java;

     import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

 public class GreetingClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter Server Address: ");
  String serverName;
  serverName = userInput.next(); 

  System.out.println("Enter Port Number: ");
  String port;
  port = userInput.next(); 


  try
  {
     System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                         + " on port " + port);
     Socket client = new Socket(serverName, Integer.parseInt(port));
     System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
     OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
     DataOutputStream out =
                   new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

     System.out.println("Enter a first number: ");

      //userInput.nextInt();
      Integer x= userInput.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter a second number: ");
    //  userInput.nextInt();
      Integer y= userInput.nextInt();


    //  System.out.println("hello");


      out.writeInt(x);
      out.writeInt(y);

     InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
     DataInputStream in =
                    new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
     System.out.println("Server responds: " +in.readInt());
     client.close();
  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}
}

Server.Java

```
   `        package Client.java;

  import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.Scanner;

   public class GreetingServer extends Thread
  {
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
     serverSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
    }

    public void run()
    {
    while(true)
      {
     try
     {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
        serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Just connected to "
              + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        DataInputStream in =
              new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());





   Integer x=in.readInt();
   System.out.println("Hellox");
   Integer y=in.readInt();
    System.out.println("Helloy");

       // System.out.println(x);
        //System.out.println(y);


        Integer sum = ( x + y );
        DataOutputStream out =
             new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

    //  System.out.println(sum);
        out.write(sum);




        server.close();
     }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
     {
        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
        break;
     }catch(IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
     }
    }
   }
     public static void main(String [] args)
       {

  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please specify a port number (1~65535): ");
  String port;
  port = userInput.next(); 

  try
  {
     Thread t = new GreetingServer(Integer.parseInt(port));
     t.start();
  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
      }`
```

Comment: How are you entering the two numbers into the console, `1 2` or `1` you press enter then `2` and enter again ?

Comment: 1 then press enter , it will ask for second number then i will enter 2

Comment: In that case you have to consume the new line before reading the next `int`, you have to call `userInput.nextLine()`.

Comment: I added userInput.nextLine() before Integer x=... and Integer y=..... lines. Still the same issue.

Comment: You should also add it between `Integer x = ...` and `Integer y = ...`. Also, you should use `int` instead of `Integer`

Comment: Thats what i did...see below System.out.println("Enter a first number: ");
        
          userInput.nextLine();
          Integer x= userInput.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter a second number: ");
         userInput.nextLine();
          Integer y= userInput.nextInt();

Comment: I guess the problem is caused by something else, you should use a debugger to see what is happening or at least add some print statements to check if you get the values from the user and if you successfully write them to the output stream.

Answer (score 1):

In your server program, replace

```
out.write(sum);
```

with

```
out.writeInt(sum);
```

If you notice, you are correctly using `out.writeInt` in your client program.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, from Brazil:

```
public class SocketSomaClient {
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int porta = 5050;
        String ip = "localhost";
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, porta);

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("Entre com o primeiro número: ");
            int x= userInput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Entre com o segundo número: ");
            int y= userInput.nextInt();

            output.writeInt(x);
            output.writeInt(y);

            DataInputStream  input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            int soma = input.readInt();
            System.out.println("A soma dos dois números é: "+ soma);

        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class SocketSomaServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5050);

                while(true){
                    // aguarda conexões
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    try{
                    // recupera os dados
                    DataInputStream  input = 
                            new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    Integer x = input.readInt();
                    Integer y = input.readInt();

                    Integer sum = ( x + y );
                    DataOutputStream out =
                         new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeInt(sum);

                 }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
                 {
                    System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                    break;
                 }catch(IOException e)
                 {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                 }
                }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server what is being written to the output stream. As you write without providing the data type. You need to retrieve in similar fashion.

```
 Integer sum = ( x + y );
    DataOutputStream out =
         new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

//  System.out.println(sum);
    out.write(sum);
```

while reading in the client just use read as below.

```
InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server responds: " +in.read());
```

Do not specify int type as show above.

Please find the complete code below.

**Client Code**

```
    package Client.java;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreetingClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Server Address: ");
        String serverName;
        serverName = userInput.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Port Number: ");
        String port;
        port = userInput.next();

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, Integer.parseInt(port));
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            System.out.println("Enter a first number: ");

//userInput.nextInt();
            Integer x = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter a second number: ");
//  userInput.nextInt();
            Integer y = userInput.nextInt();

//  System.out.println("hello");

            out.writeInt(x);
            out.writeInt(y);

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            System.out.println("Server responds: " + in.read());
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Code**

```
package Client.java;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());

                Integer x = in.readInt();
                System.out.println("Hellox");
                Integer y = in.readInt();
                System.out.println("Helloy");

                // System.out.println(x);
                // System.out.println(y);

                Integer sum = (x + y);
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                // System.out.println(sum);
                out.write(sum);

                server.close();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please specify a port number (1~65535): ");
        String port;
        port = userInput.next();

        try {
            Thread t = new GreetingServer(Integer.parseInt(port));
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```